# Change the background according to an input

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I have created a tabbed temperature converter.  One tab provides the converter and the other is a `UIWebView` using google to find local weather temperature.  Now I want to make it even better by making my background in the first tab which is the converter to change according to the user's input in the `UITextField`.  For example, I want a snowy picture that I would import to show up if the inputed string is less than 0. So I am using the following if and else statement.  Xcode doesn't give me an error, but the code doesn't work.  Would someone please help me to complete my project.  Thanks in advance! This is my if and else code:

```
-(UITextField *)startingTemperatureTextField {
if (startingTemperatureTextField.text < 0)
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Snowy Background.png"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string with an int. Use intValue to get the int value of the string.

```
    -(UITextField *)startingTemperatureTextField {
        if ([startingTemperatureTextField.text intValue] < 0){
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage       imageNamed:@"Snowy Background.png"]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: so I followed this, but the background did not change.

Comment: please help! I really need to get this portion of my app to work. tnx

Comment: Could you maybe give some more info or show some more code? I guess you have checked the image name, but incorrect image name will not raise an error, just turn your background black.

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
-(UITextField *)startingTemperatureTextField {
     if (![startingTemperatureTextField.text length] > 0 ){
          [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Snowy Background.png"]]];
     }
}
```

### EDIT

I've completely misunderstood you question! Sorry!

So... you want to change the background if the user inputs a value into your "startingTemperatureTextField" that is less than 0, so i guess that somewhere in your code you have used this method :

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
```

just change this method like this :

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
       if( textField == self.startingTemperatureTextField ){

            if ([self.startingTemperatureTextField.text intValue] < 0 ){
                 [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Snowy Background.png"]]];
        }
    }
    textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work either.  So when the the input is less than 0, the same background stays on.

Comment: So you were right, I did have that code. I changed it with yours but the background still doesn't work.  So let me tell you this as well: in my '.xib' file I've dragged in a UIImageView and have chosen a background that shows up as part of the UI and when the app lunches.  And I want that background to change later according to an user's input. Now is there something wrong? thank you so much!

Comment: Oh this just happened, I am using your code and when I type something in the textfield and press return, xcode gives me the green line saying : "thread 1: breakpoint 1.1".  What should i do?